# HP Elitebook keyboard issues

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I own a HP Elitebook 840 G3. I'm a student and I was trying to fix an issue with the keyboard doing some janky stuff (typing in say the g key would open browser history on Firefox) so I decided to open my laptop. I got to the keyboard, unplugged it and then plugged it back in. Now the qweruiop keys don't work, and I'm wondering if I caused that or if this is something else. Please help as soon as possible, I have a lot of schoolwork that can only be done on a laptop and I don't have another laptop. Thanks! :)

Edit: I have taken apart and replugged everything in a few times, I'm starting to think I may have damaged a connection so I'm assuming I'll have to buy a new keyboard

Comment: Take the laptop apart again, unplug the keyboard, and then plug it back in very carefully and fully. Reassemble and test.

Comment: I have just done this, tested and yay! The keys were working, except now my number keys don't work so I'm opening it back up again. I'm being extra careful. Thank you John

Answer (score 0):

As far as we can tell, the keyboard connector still seems to be functional, don't give up hope yet.

The ideal solution would be to try to give the keyboard connector contacts a clean with some Isopropyl Alcohol and a cotton swab to allow effective flow of electricity, plugging the keyboard back in (doing your best not to touch the contacts) and re-testing.

That would definitely be worth a try if you're up for it. It could just be a case of stubborn dirt. If that doesn't work, **and** you've ruled out the possibility of software causing the problem, it would probably make sense to replace the keyboard with a new one.

Comment: Hi! I tried that, has not worked. If it would be helpful I can send along a picture with the connector that I think may have the problem.

If it is a software problem, could you link to a website or something that explains how to fix this issue?